# Missing first document when loading multi-document yaml file in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyyaml

I tried to load a multi-document yaml file (i.e., a yaml file consting of multiple yaml documents separated by "---") into a Pandas dataframe. For some reason, the first document does not end up in the dataframe. If the output of `yaml.safe_load_all` is first materialized into a list (instead of feeding the iterator to `pd.io.json.json_normalize`),all documents end up in the dataframe. I could reproduce this with the example code below (on an entirely different yaml file).

```py
import os
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

# public example of multi-document yaml
inputfilepath = os.path.expanduser("~/my_example.yaml")
url =  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, inputfilepath) 

with open(inputfilepath, 'r') as stream:
     df1 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.safe_load_all(stream))

with open(inputfilepath, 'r') as stream:
     df2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize([ x for x in yaml.safe_load_all(stream)])

print(f'Output table shape with iterator: {df1.shape}')
print(f'Output table shape with iterator materialized as list: {df2.shape}')
```

I expect both results to be identical, but I get:

```
Output table shape with iterator: (5, 18)
Output table shape with iterator materialized as list: (6, 18)
```

Any ideas why these results differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this site for [list comprehension vs. generator expressions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db/).

`df1` is missing the first row of data because you are passing a *iterator* instead of an *iterable*.

```
print(yaml.safe_load_all(stream))
#Output: <generator object load_all at 0x00000293E1697750>
```

From the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), it is expecting a list:

> data : dict or list of dicts

#### Update for more detail:

From looking into the `normalize.py` source file, the function `json_normalize` has this conditional check that's making it so your generator is treated like you passed in a nested structure:

```
if any([isinstance(x, dict)
    for x in compat.itervalues(y)] for y in data):
        # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
        # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for
        # deeply nested structures:
        #  {VeryLong: { b: 1,c:2}} -> {VeryLong.b:1 ,VeryLong.c:@}
        #
        # TODO: handle record value which are lists, at least error
        #       reasonably
        data = nested_to_record(data, sep=sep)
    return DataFrame(data)
```

Inside of the `nested_to_record` function:

```
new_d = copy.deepcopy(d)
for k, v in d.items():
    # each key gets renamed with prefix
    if not isinstance(k, compat.string_types):
        k = str(k)
    if level == 0:
        newkey = k
    else:
        newkey = prefix + sep + k

    # only dicts gets recurse-flattend
    # only at level>1 do we rename the rest of the keys
    if not isinstance(v, dict):
        if level != 0:  # so we skip copying for top level, common case
            v = new_d.pop(k)
            new_d[newkey] = v
        continue
    else:
        v = new_d.pop(k)
        new_d.update(nested_to_record(v, newkey, sep, level + 1))
new_ds.append(new_d)
```

The line `d.items()` is where your generator is evaluated and inside the loop is where you can see they skip the first "level", which in your case is the first record.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for looking into this! I think this should be catched by pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26646